# AS3 timer is faster than php

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

Im trying too load new messages every second, but new messages are doubled everytime they are loaded, I suppose because the timer is completed before the php is executed?
so I tried to add

```
  if (checker != "" + idstored + "done") {
checker =  "" + idstored + "done";
```

so that once the timer completes, it changes the checker so that when the timer restarts and finishes again it would not execute again... but it stopped checking for all new messages... any tips??

```
var count:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
count.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete); 
count.start();

var checker;
function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void{
    if (checker != "" + idstored + "done") {
    checker =  "" + idstored + "done";

    var variables_cc:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    var varSend_cc:URLRequest = new URLRequest("chat.php");
    varSend_cc.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    varSend_cc.data = variables_cc;
    var varLoader_cc:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
    varLoader_cc.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    varLoader_cc.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler_cc);

    function completeHandler_cc(event:Event):void{
        if (event.target.data.statusline == "is_new") {
              stored_id_txt.text = "" + event.target.data.stored_id;
              status_txt.text = "" + event.target.data.statusline;
              returnline.text = "" + event.target.data.returnBody;
              checker.text = checker;
              splitByDelimiter(event.target.data.returnBody);
              idstored = event.target.data.stored_id;
              checker = "refresh";
        } 
    }}
    // ready the last_refresh_time variable for sending to PHP
    variables_cc.requester = "chat_check";
    variables_cc.stored_id = idstored;
    varLoader_cc.load(varSend_cc);
    count.reset();
    count.start();
}
```

Comment: You should place the timer reset code within the Event Complete Handler, else the timer may be reset before the URL Request is complete.

Comment: tried that... didnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get errors becouse you sometimes try to start new download when the previous is not finished. It's not wise to do something latency dependent every 1 second real time. You need to start something, wait for it to finish, and then start it again.

removeEventListener of the timer after it launches (inside onTimerComplete function) and stop the timer and reset it. qddEventListener to the timer and start it after the data is downloaded (inside completeHangler_cc function).

Comment: tried it soo many times with variations... it came down to the php file... i had if and else statements in the php, the else statement wasnt properly echoing the line flash needed.